# discover a param in APIView swagger

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have an APIView object as-is :

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema

class SimulationGenerator(APIView):

    @swagger_auto_schema()
    def post(self, request) -> Response:
        """create a simulation"""
        simulation_id = request.data["simulation_id"]
        create_simulation(simulation_id)
        return Response(status=200, data=f"Job with simu_id : {simulation_id} created")
```

and my URL is:

```py
from django.urls import path

from .views import SimulationGenerator

urlpatterns = [
    path("simulation/", SimulationGenerator.as_view()),
]
```

Having this, my API is called doing :

```
POST simulation/
```

with a body :

```json
{ 
     "simulation_id" : "foo"
}
```

But when I call my swagger, my `params` are empty :

```json
"post": {
    "parameters": [],
```

How can I make `swagger_auto_schema` discover that I need a `simulation_id` param ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use DRF [Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) to declare required request field.

```
class SimulationIdSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    simulation_id = serializers.IntegerField()
```

and use it like:

```
...
class SimulationGenerator(APIView):

    @swagger_auto_schema(method='post', request_body=SimulationIdSerializer)
    def post(self, request) -> Response:
        """create a simulation"""
...
```

drf-yasg has [docs](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#the-swagger-auto-schema-decorator) and an [example project](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/tree/master/testproj). This is not the only way to specify parameters and response classes.